# Creating a Poll application. Need advice on database structure for the vote count

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema, database-schema

I'm writing an application to allow users to create a Poll. They ask a **question** and set `n` number of predefined **answers** to the question. Other users can vote on the answers provided for that question.

## Current structure

I have designed the database like this:

[image: Database strucure diagram]

## Storing the vote count

Current thinking is, I create a new column called `vote_count` on the `link` table and every time that answer gets voted, it updates the record.

This works. But is it right? I'm new to database systems, so I can't imagine I'm doing much right. What are some more efficient ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it goes yes that's OK. However these tables will be incomplete. When your second quiz is created, you'll have to extend the QUESTIONS table. If this second quiz's Q1 also has a yes/no answer, you're going to have to extend the LINK/VOTES table.

You also have to think about how it's going to be queried and design indexes to support those queries.

Cheers -